# How to set Finnish locale in java?

Tags: java, methods, locale, getter

Topic says it all.
The Locale.class seems to include some languages but I can't find Finnish among them.
**How do I get the finnish Locale?** I need to set it as an argument to a method. Thank you.

the method is as follows:

```
public String getMessage(String tag, Locale locale) { 
...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply create the `Locale` object with the desired language and country code, for example:

```
Locale finnish = new Locale("fi", "FI");
```

You're not restricted to the constants that are defined in the `Locale` class.

See the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

Comment: That was exactomundo what I needed. Just before daily scrum ;) Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 0):

```
list of supported locale.


 Locale locales[] = SimpleDateFormat.getAvailableLocales();
        for (int i = 0; i < locales.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%10s - %s, %s \n" , locales[i].toString(),locales[i].getDisplayName(), locales[i].getDisplayCountry());

        }
```